# ¿Por qué no es posible modificar un carácter de una cadena, pero sí un elemento de una lista?

Tags: python, string, tipos, mutabilidad

Si yo tengo una lista, `lista=[1,23,6]` y...

- quiero ver su primer valor simplemente debo hacer `print(lista[0])`,
- quiero saber su tamaño `print(len(lista))`
- quiero modificar el primer valor hago `lista[0]=0`.

Ahora bien, yo en mi caso quiero trabajar con cadenas de hexadecimales.

Si por ejemplo yo tengo una cadena como la siguiente, `p = b'\x0A\x05\xFF'` y...

- quiero saber su primer valor (un 10 decimal), puedo hacer al igual que en las listas `print(p[0])`,
- quiero saber la longitud, también funciona bien haciendo `print(len(p))`.

**En cambio**, si lo que quiero es modificarla, `p[0]=b'\x0B'` me da error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8ac3493bac88> in <module>
----> 1 p[0]=b'\x0B'

TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

La pregunta es, ¿por qué esta acción no funciona y las otras sí? ¿Cómo se haría?

Comment: No es una duda tonta, ni la respuesta tan obvia. Buena pregunta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes modificarla porque una cadena (ya sea de caracteres o de bytes) es un tipo **inmutable** a diferencia de las listas.

La inmutabilidad se refiere precisamente a ese comportamiento que has observado, y es que no se puede modificar un elemento particular. Lo mismo pasa con las tuplas.

## Cómo cambiar entonces un byte dentro

Directamente no se puede, como ya ha quedado claro. Pero tienes alternativas:

- Crear una nueva cadena de bytes idéntica a la tuya, excepto por el carácter que quieres cambiar
- Usar un `bytearray` en lugar de una cadena de bytes.

### Creando una nueva

La primera opción sería algo así:

```
def modificar_byte(cadena, posicion, nuevo_valor):
   return cadena[:posicion] + nuevo_valor +  cadena[posicion+1:]
```

Ejemplo:

```
p = b'\x0A\x05\xFF'
p = modificar_byte(p, 0, b'\x0b')
print(p)
```

Resulta en `b'\x0b\x05\xff'` ¿Cómo es que esto funciona? ¿No se está saltando la restricción de inmutabilidad?

Lo cierto es que no. La función no ha modificado la secuencia original de bytes, sino que ha creado una nueva concatenando trozos de la secuencia original con el byte recibido como parámetro. El resultado es una **nueva** cadena de bytes que es retornada por la función. El programa principal asigna esa nueva secuencia a la misma variable `p`. Lo que ocurre entonces es que `p` antes se refería (*apuntaba a*) una cadena de bytes, y después se refiere (*apunta a*) otra diferente. La original sigue en memoria, inmutable y separada de la nueva. Pero pronto Python la retirará de la memoria al descubrir que ya no tiene referencias (variables que *apunten* a ella).

El resultado práctico es que aparentemente has cambiado un byte dentro de `p`, pero como ves siguiendo un camino bastante tortuoso y poco eficiente.

### Usando bytearray

Por ello, si vas a necesitar cambiar muchos bytes, es mejor usar un `bytearray`, que es una estructura mutable, similar a una lista, pero cuyos elementos son bytes, y que puede usarse en la mayoría de contextos en los que se espera una cadena de bytes.

Con este enfoque sería así:

```
p = bytearray(b'\x0A\x05\xFF')

# Ya puedes modificar sus elementos, aunque cambia la sintaxis ya que debes
# asignarle enteros y no cadenas. Los enteros pueden darse en hex
p[0] = 0x0b
```

Puedes mantener `p` como bytearray mientras necesites modificar sus elementos. Cuando ya no lo vayas a modificar más puedes "congelarlo" a una cadena de bytes inmutable:

```
p = bytes(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

En Python, las cadenas son inmutables. También son inmutables int, float, bool, unicode y tuple. Son mutables list, dict y set.

Es por ello que puedes modificar una lista, diccionario o set, pero no un string.